# webclient.download downloading incomplete tiff image from a url

Tags: c#-3.0, lotus-domino

I am using below code to download a tiff file from a lotus domino server.

```
string url
    = "http://10.1.1.23\\Domino\\ImageDb.nsf\\500-99-9o9\\$File\\abc.tif";

// Create an instance of WebClient
WebClient client = new WebClient();

string filename 
    = "c:\\test.tif";

client.DownloadFile(url,filename);
```

But the file which is downloaded is of 4kb instead of 22kb and when i try to open it, its says its in improper/invalid format. Any guesses what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have anonymous access to the file? Can you download the file in your browser?

Comment: it asks for my user name and password when i try to download it in my web browser.

Comment: That explains why you can't download the file in c#. You need to provide credentials. The 4 KB file is probably a HTML page with the login window :-)

Comment: You should also provide a valid URL: don't use backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), you will see that the 4kb file is the authentication HTML page that Domino automatically presents when an un-authenticated request for content is made via HTTP and the particular resource requested is not accessible anonymously.

In this case, it sounds like when you request this file resource in Domino, you will need to authenticate.

You can do this by providing a valid LTPToken in the request header, which is issued by the Domino server once you have authenticated. Alternatively, if authentication is not possible you can make the database ACL, and document accessible to "anonymous" users. Although not specifically C# code, these links will help you understand about LTPA on Domino, [here](http://www.dominoexperts.com/articles/Creating-a-session-for-a-user), [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Lightweight_Third-Party_Authentication) and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21306272)